# Is there a way to create a pdf from information inputted in a form via PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

I am developing a site for local govt. organisation and they need a function where they can create agendas and meeting minutes from a html form in a secure area. My question is, is it possible to do this? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although you will need to use some sort of library that isn't part of PHP. Different libraries offer varying degrees of control over the formatting of the output.

Alternatively, you could use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) or a headless Chrome solution to convert HTML to PDF, which gives you a high degree of control over the output, at the cost of some complexity.